# TypeError: Webpack imported module is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a backend that calculates work shifts.
I am trying to post some required user input with a module in services/shifts.
The getAll method works fine, but posting throws an error

> TypeError: _services_shifts__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.postData is not a function

Shiftservice module:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = '...'

const getAll = () => {
    const request = axios.get(baseUrl)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}
const postData = newObject => {
    const request = axios.post(baseUrl, newObject)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}

export default {getAll, postData}
```

I have a button that triggers the following calling code on click:

```
import shiftService from './services/shifts'

  const postData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const sampleObject = {
      sampleField: sample
    }
    shiftService
      .postData(sampleObject)
      .then(returnedData => {
        console.log(returnedData)
      })
}
```

When execution reaches shiftService.postData, the error is thrown.

I am really confused since I am basically copying some older project of mine which works, but here I just don't find the problem. Thank you in advance for helping a newcomer!

Comment: What does `shiftService` look like?

Comment: The first code block. Edited my question to make that clear :)

Comment: If you console log `shiftService` in the calling code is it actually defined? Can you see the object with the correct properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I am embarrassed of the solution. I was just editing an earlier version of shiftService from a wrong folder, and the imported service only had the get method in it...

So my code actually works if placed correctly. Thank you for your time, and thanks for sharing alternative ways that must work aswell.

Answer (score 13):

Modules provide special export default ***(“the default export”)*** syntax to make the ***“one thing per module”*** way look better.***There may be only one export default per file***.And we may neglect the name of the class in the following example.

```
 //Module1
export default class{
}
```

And then import it without curly braces with any name:

```
//Module2
import anyname from './Module1'
```

Your scenario is different having two functions.You can either export default one function

```
export default getAll
```

and normal export the other function.

```
export postData
```

and when importing

```
import{ default as getAll,postData} from './yourModule'
```

**OR**

Remove `default` here in Shiftservice module and export normally:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = '...'

const getAll = () => {
    const request = axios.get(baseUrl)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}
const postData = newObject => {
    const request = axios.post(baseUrl, newObject)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}

export {getAll, postData}
```

Importing in your module

```
import {getAll,PostData} from './Module1'
```

or

```
import * as shiftService from './Module1'
```

and then use `shiftServer.postData()`.....

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat embarrassing, but in my case the issue was that I had both `module.js` and `module.ts` in the same directory as a result of a refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I think its becuse your declaring the function as arrow functions
and export it this way:

`export default {getAll, postData}`

you need to declare them as a normal functions

```
function postData(){
}
```

that should work

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when importing a part of a module without curly brackets.

```
import {part} from 'mymodule'; // works

import part from 'mymodule'; // calling part() throws this error
// Uncaught TypeError: part__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16___default(...) is not a function
```