# Error importing private repo into next project

Tags: reactjs, import, next.js, importerror

I am trying to import a private github repo to use it on a React/Next project, however it throws an error saying that there are currently no loaders configured, I don't think that is actually the problem I imported other `.TS` files on this project, just not directly from a repository, so I suspect I'm missing something when importing.

The repository is very simple, all it has is a `README` and the `Comms.ts` file.

Here is the repo on my package.json:

```
"my-library": "git+https://ghp_mYpErsOnaLAcCeSSToKenOnGithUb1234567:x-oauth-basic@github.com/My-Repo/my-library.git"
```

Here is how I am importing it on my project:

```
import * as Comms from "my-library"
```

The error:

```
./node_modules/my-library/Comms.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:50)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|
> export const FetchTokenIdsFromWallet=async(account: string, collectionAddr: string, chain: string)=>{
|   
|   const requestString = 'https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/' + account + '/nft/' + collectionAddr + '?chain=' + chain + '&format=decimal'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was indeed on the loader. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64990954/5844134) to see how to add the loader, basically add the loader with

```
yarn add ts-loader --dev
```

Then add the webpack to your `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts)x?$/, // Just `tsx?` file only
      use: [
        // options.defaultLoaders.babel, I don't think it's necessary to have this loader too
        {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            experimentalWatchApi: true,
            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    return config
  }
}
```

If after this you get an error saying something like `_your_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.yourFunc is not a function` check if you are exporting your functions in the correct way, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61853964/5844134). If you are exporting them the right way, try running `yarn upgrade`

Relevant docs:

[webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)

[custom webpack for next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config)